# Get current subsite SPDocumentLibrary

Tags: 2010

I have many subsite levels, and in the last one I have a pages library.
I want to access it by code, the following code says the LIST does not exist.

When I debugged, the URL of SPContext.Current.Site is the sitecollection url not

/site/site1/site3

so the SpDocumentlibrary line says that list does not exist.

on the ribbon ations

```
var options = {              
            url: '{SiteUrl}/_layouts/xxx/MoveFiles.aspx?items=' + myItems + '&amp;source=' + SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList()  + '&amp;url=' + SP.ClientContext.get_current().get_web().Url ,





protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["items"] != null && Request.QueryString["source"] != null)
        {
            string source = Request.QueryString["source"];
            string url = Request.QueryString["url"];

            string[] items = Request.QueryString["items"].ToString().Split('|');
            LabelItems.Text = "You have selected the following items to move:<br><br>";
            source = source.Substring(1, source.Length - 2).ToLower();
            Guid sourceID = new Guid(source);

            //SPUtility.GetPageUrlPath(SPContext.Current);

            string SiteUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;//Get the url of current site
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteUrl))
            {
                //open the site with the url passed
                using (SPWeb oWeb = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPDocumentLibrary sourceDocLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)oWeb.Lists["Site Pages"];
                    //SPDocumentLibrary sourceDocLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Site Pages"];

                    ListItems = new System.Collections.Generic.List<SPListItem>();
                    for (int i = 1; i < items.Length; i++)
                    {
                        SPListItem currentListItem = sourceDocLib.GetItemById(int.Parse(items[i]));
                        ListItems.Add(currentListItem);
                        LabelItems.Text += currentListItem.Name + "<br>";
                    }
                }
            }         
        }
    }
```

UPDATE

1. My sites are like this:
   http://servername

http://servername/TestWorkSpace

http://servername/TestWorkSpace/Wiki

So, in the wiki subsite I have a Site Pages Library.  And on that context, the new ribbon button appears.

I tried using the {SPUrl} as explained below, but it returns me only this part:
http://servername/TestWorkSpace

I need to be able to create a SPWeb object based on:
http://servername/TestWorkSpace/Wiki

I updated the code above.!!!

Comment: Where is this running from? Depending on that SPContext.Current.X could be so many different things.

Comment: this is an application page that I launch with a new button from the ribbon, the application page is obviously deployed to the layouts folder, that might be the reason? No matter what I do, it always returns me the sitecollection site.

Comment: I could be remembering incorrectly but I want to say context should still work there. The caveat is that the application page could technically be ran from any site. For example it could be http://server/_layouts/page.aspx or http://server/sub1/sub2/sub3/_layouts/page.aspx - if the path you are using to open the page includes the subsites then maybe you really can't get the context?

Comment: please see the update in how I am opening the dialog.

Comment: Facing same issue - what was the fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ribbon button the /_layouts/...  will end up with a site collection relative url instead of a web relative url. In your command action when you define your ribbon button you can use the {SiteUrl} tag (which is replaced with the current web URL at run time) to generate a full URL to the application page that includes the current site. See [this question and answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/30721/6530) for more details.

For the server side of things you want to use SPContext.Current.Web instead of SPContext.Current.Site.

In the API an SPWeb refers to a site and all configuration options / content associated to it and an SPSite is the general configuration / properties of the Site Collection as a whole. (SPSite.RootWeb would give you the top level site - e.g.)

Comment: no, that doesnt not work either, it still says the list does not exist at url ....

Comment: Updated my answer based on feedback.

Comment: Hi, Almost there, please see my update, I could get a reference to the parent site of the subsite, but not yet to the subsite, I need to be able to create a SPDocumentLibrary object thats on the subsite level.

Comment: So you must be hitting the button from a page on http://servername/TestWorkSpace? Also you are still using SPContext.Current.Site instead of SPContext.Current.Web according to your code.

Comment: indeed, my mistake, it works now. give me few minutes to test and I will come back

Answer (score 0):

I just passed the `{SiteUrl}` as a Query String parameter and it solved my problem.

As i'm using `CustomAction` -> `UrlAction` and i'm passing this query string parameter.